# Checkbox that make many pictures visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am quite new to js and html and have some problems with a task.  I want to create a "checkbox" that will make some pictures visible. For example I have 5 pictures. On each picture there is a male or female. Now i want to make all female picures visible if someone check the "female checkbox". I think that I will need to create some datatable (?) in js but not sure how to do it.

This is what I created so far

```js
  function toggleVisibility(id) {
           var el = document.getElementById(id);

          if (el.style.visibility=="visible") {
              el.style.visibility="hidden";
                }
            else {
                 el.style.visibility="visible";
                 }
         }
```

```html
<div class='Humans'>

    <label for="menu">male</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="malecheck" onChange="checkpaycondition('1');" /><br/>

    <label for="menu">female</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="femalecheck" onChange="checkpaycondition('2');" /><br/>

    <label for="picture">Person1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Person1check" onChange="toggleVisibility('4');" /><br/>

    <label for="picture">Person2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Person2check" onChange="toggleVisibility('1');" /><br/>

    <label for="picture">Person3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Person3check" onChange="toggleVisibility('2');" /><br/>

    <label for="picture">Person4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Person4check" onChange="toggleVisibility('3');" /><br/>

    <label for="picture">Person5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Person5check" onChange="toggleVisibility('5');" /><br/>

    <img id='1' src='/home/Person1.png'  style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--male-->
    <img id='2' src='/home/Person2.png'  style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--female-->
    <img id='3' src='/home/Person3.png'  style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--female-->
    <img id='4' src='/home/Person4.png'  style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--male-->
    <img id='5' src='/home/Person5.png'  style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--female-->
    </div>
```

Any idea how I can get this to work? Hope you can help.

Cheers!

Comment: Is jQuery an option as suggested by question's tag? FYI, IDs ***must be unique*** on document context

Comment: ids are SINGLAR! You have the same id "check" over and over.

Comment: I prefer js (or rather i am forced to use js) but for now jquery is ok as well since a working code is better than no code.

EDIT. Yes, i forgot to change the id in input. Thx!

Comment: Well you need a way to say that the image is male or female. Until you come up with that [data attribute or class], there is nothing you can do.

Comment: one option is to add data-* attribute to your img tags, for instance data-gender="female", (more info on data-* attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_data) with jQuery it would be easy to select those elements, but with JavaScript you would probably have to loop child elements of <div class='Humans'> to look for the right attribute match(es)

Comment: @epascarello Is there a tutorial how to do that data attribute or class? Unfortunately i just started with js/html and have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your HTML; it's usually better to use classes when dealing with a group of elements --- it's harder using ids. Here are some changes I have made:

- Removed inline JavaScript -- it's not recommended
- Removed inline CSS -- not recommended either
- Added a class instead of inline css and define a rule
- Added two event handlers instead of inline JS
- Changed you `:checkbox` ids to `name`s instead
- Removed IDs from `img` elements
- Added a `data` attribute to each image, `data-gender` to be used with `name="gender"`
- Added a `value` attribute to each `:checkbox`
- **BONUS** added one proper use of IDs -- label for attribute -- click label to check/uncheck

As you can see, once your HTML is well designed, writing your JavaScript and CSS is a piece of cake.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Event handler for checkboxes with name="gender"
    $(':checkbox[name=gender]').on('change',function() {
        $('img[data-gender=' + this.value + ']').css('visibility', this.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    });
    //Event handler for checkboxes with name="visibility"
    $(':checkbox[name=visibility]').on('change', function() {
        $('img[src*=' + this.value + ']').css('visibility',this.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
.myimage {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='Humans'>

    <label for="gender1">male</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gender1" value="male" /><br/>

    <label for="gender2">female</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gender2" value="female" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility1">Person1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility1" value="Person1" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility2">Person2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility2" value="Person2" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility3">Person3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility3" value="Person3" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility4">Person4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility4" value="Person4" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility5">Person5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility5" value="Person5" /><br/>

    <img src='/home/Person1.png' data-gender="male" class="myimage"/> <!--male-->
    <img src='/home/Person2.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage"/> <!--female-->
    <img src='/home/Person3.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage"/> <!--female-->
    <img src='/home/Person4.png' data-gender="male" class="myimage"/> <!--male-->
    <img src='/home/Person5.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage"/> <!--female-->
    </div>
```

Comment: Thx! I also have a question. What is this line? 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You're welcome. ... That's how you include jQuery from a CDN. As you may know already, jQuery allows you to write much less code than you would without it.

Comment: Oh, ok. And is there a way to do it with just JS? I am not sure if I am allowed to use jquerry.

Comment: Would you like to give it a try based on the updated HTML? If you still can't figure it out, I would recommend asking a new question, clearly showing how far you were able to go. By selecting a `jQuery` tag you indicated that a `jQuery` answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change id to something string_with_number.

For example:
id="image1"... etc

Then you can use this function with having 
var el = document.getElementById("image"+id);

and instead of visibility, you should use display: block and display: none

Comment: You did not read the question... ids can start with a number in modern browsers.